# Could not find installable ISAM (in 'throw ex;' line)

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio-2015

I'm trying to upload csv file and the data saved into the local database. But when i run my code it stated 'Could not find installable ISAM'. I'm not sure how to fix it. I have researched and most errors are in their connection. But mine is highlighted on a different code.

How do i fix it?

My code:

```
        const string CSV_CONNECTIONSTRING = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=\"{0}\";Extended Properties=\"csv;HDR=YES;FMT=Delimited\"";


        string csvPath = Server.MapPath("~/Files1/");
        string fileName = Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);
        FileUpload1.SaveAs(Path.Combine(csvPath, fileName));
        var AllFiles = new DirectoryInfo(csvPath).GetFiles("*csv");
        string File_Name = string.Empty;


        string ConString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;

        for (int i = 0; i < AllFiles.Length; i++)
        {
            try
            {
                File_Name = AllFiles[i].Name;
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                using (OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(string.Format(CSV_CONNECTIONSTRING, csvPath)))
                {
                    using (OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [Mcsv]", con))
                    {
                        da.Fill(dt);
                    }
                }
                using (SqlBulkCopy bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(ConString))
                {
                    bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add(0, "medicine_id");
                    bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add(1, "category_id");
                    bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add(2, "subcategory_id");
                    bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "medicine";
                    bulkCopy.BatchSize = dt.Rows.Count;
                    bulkCopy.WriteToServer(dt);
                    bulkCopy.Close();
                }
            }
            catch (System.Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
```

The error shown to be at 'throw ex;'

Comment: there are a lot of csv parsers that don't use ado.net

Comment: i still dont get it..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is with the connection string. A different piece of code is highlighted as you have an Exception handler which has caught the Exception when trying to use the connection and re-thrown it.

In the connection string, change `csv` to `text`

```
const string CSV_CONNECTIONSTRING = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=\"{0}\";Extended Properties=\"text;HDR=YES;FMT=Delimited\"";
```

This should fix the could not find installable ISAM error.

Next, you'll probably get an error that it can't find Mcsv.txt. In the SELECT statement, change `[Mcsv]` to be the filename you wish to read.

```
using (OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [" + File_Name + "]", con))
```

Comment: Mcsv is the file. i had the mcsv.txt problem previously too and i changed the text to csv in the connection string. Now, I created another file in .txt format with the same content as the csv file however, I tried to read it but the error still shows it cant find the file.txt

Comment: Oh wait! i copy ur exact codes and it worked ^^ Thanks @James xD